# Sharing ViewModel between SwiftUI components

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'd like to implement a navigator/router for an architecture implemented with SwiftUI and Combine. In a few words the `View` will share `viewModel` with `Router`. When the `View` triggers a change on the `viewModel` the `Router` should navigate to a new sheet.

This is a version of my code where I'm directly passing the `viewModel` from `View` to `Router`. Is there anything wrong? My biggest doubt is that since I'm using `@ObservedObject` on both the `Router` and the `View`, two different instances of the `viewModel` are created.

## VIEW MODEL

```
class BootViewModel:ObservableObject{
    @Published var presentSignIn = false
}
```

## VIEW

```
struct BootView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel:BootViewModel
    var navigator:BootNavigator<BootView>? = nil

    init(viewModel:BootViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        self.navigator = BootNavigator(view: self, viewModel: viewModel)
        self.navigator.setSubscriptions()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello")
            Button("Button"){
                self.viewModel.presentSignIn.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## NAVIGATOR

```
class BootNavigator<T:View>{
    var view:T? = nil
    @ObservedObject var viewModel:BootViewModel

    init(view:T, viewModel:BootViewModel) {
        self.view = view
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    func setSubscriptions(){
        subscribe(onSigninPressed: $viewModel.presentSignIn)
    }


    func subscribe(onSigninPressed : Binding<Bool>){
        _ = view.sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.presentSignIn){
            SignInView()
        }
    }
}
```

- Why the `SignInView` is never presented?
- Without taking into account the fact that using a router with swiftUI is not needed in general(I'm mostly doing an exercise)... is there anything wrong with this implementation?

Answer (score 2):

This

```
view.sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.presentSignIn){
    SignInView()
```

**MUST** be somewhere in `body` (directly or via computed property or func) but inside body's ViewBuilder

Comment: do you mind to share a link to official doc stating that?I can’t find anything referencing this constraint

Answer (score 2):

Some notes I have to point out here:

#### ValueType

There is a difference between an `UIView` and a SwiftUI `View`. All SwiftUI `View`s are value type! So they get copied when you pass them around. Be aware of that.

#### Single instance

If you want a single instance like a regular *navigator* for your entire app, you can use singleton pattern. But there is a better approach in SwiftUI universe called `@Environment` objects. You can take advantage of that.

#### Trigger a view refresh

To refresh the view (including presenting something), you must code **inside** the `var body`. But it can be directly written on indirectly through a function or etc.

Comment: do you mind to improve the answer with code that uses @Environment to handle a Navigator? I’m a little bit confused since each of my views are going to have their dedicated Navigator...

Comment: take a look at [this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-environmentobject-property-wrapper)

Comment: Sorry your question needs lots of opinion based information and thats not allowed on SO. I tried to point out the subjects and you should follow the tail yourself. But I will be so happy to help if you had any questions about this my friend.